# Taking a screenshot of a notification breaks the PrintScreen button

Tags: 18.04, gnome, notification, screenshot

My problem is that taking a screenshot of a notification breaks the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Trigger one of those pop up notifications that appear at the top of the screen, e.g. by disconnecting from a Thunderbird server, browser notifications, etc.
2. Hover the mouse on top of the notification and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, which normally captures a window.
3. Nothing happens, and the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button should now be unresponsive.

I am able to consistently reproduce this on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). The only way of fixing the button I could find is rebooting.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to "reset" the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button if it becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Try the following - `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` , keep the terminal open, then take your screenshot using the alt+prtsc and see what populates in the terminal.  If you don't understand the output edit your question and post it.  tail -f will show the results of the keypress in as soon as you do it.

Comment: @TBr nothing was recorded on the terminal. I kept the terminal up and ran the command in the following ways: (a) normally taking an Alt+PrintScreen: nothing logged; (b) taking an Alt+PrintScreen after focussing on the notification (which disables the PrintScreen button); (c) trying to take a screenshot after triggering the PrintScreen bug. In case it was stuck on something, I left the terminal running but nothing was recorded even after waiting (besides unrelated network logs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a bug report about this issue in Launchpad, so you can file a new bug report against the `gnome-screenshot` package to let developers know about it. Read this question to know how to file a bug report: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

When <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> becomes unresponsive, restarting GNOME Shell will probably restore its functionality. To restart GNOME Shell press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.